# error 500 Layout default_email not found

Tags: joomla-3.5

I went log onto one of my websites today and got this error front end and back end

```
Layout default_email not found.
```

any ideas as to what could cause this please

I am currently running joomla 3.5.1

```
https://support.barabano.com
```

Comment: Link to site in question would be more than welcome.

Comment: sorry, i've edited the question and added the site in question

Comment: That might be caused by some missing core files Due to the fact that you can not access admin, I would recommend you to reset your Joomla by following Step 3 from http://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/how-to-reset-joomla/ by using FTP.

Comment: hi, thanks for the advice, i have followed the instruction, but unfortunately, it did not work

Comment: I can see that your site is working now (at least admin is, due to activated Offline mode). If you have fixed a problem, please share a solution with the rest of us, as a future reference...

Answer (score 0):

You are using an extension from JoomlaThat - I don't know which one, but you can find out by examining your components directory. Once you find out which one, you will need to re-install it as this will restore the file `default_email` that was probably accidentally deleted. Alternatively, you can just download the extension, extract it on your machine, and then just copy the `default_email` to the appropriate location (there are two `default_email` files and they must be copied to 2 different locations - one for the frontend and one for the backend).